# point ip to a virtual path

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a webserver asp.net with 1 ip and several domain name.

let say:
174.1.1.1

> with domain.com domain2.com domain3.com

If i go to 174.1.1.1 it show

"Under Construction
The site you are trying to view does not currently have a default page. It may be in the process of being upgraded and configured."

So If I navigate to 174.1.1.1 I want it redirect to domain2.com

so how can I do that?

I'm using visual studio 2010 with win xp and iis

Answer (score 0):

[IIS6: To redirect requests to another Web site or directory](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true)

> 1. In IIS Manager, expand the local computer, right-click the Web site or directory you want to redirect, and click Properties.
> 2. Click the Home Directory, Virtual Directory, or Directory tab.
> 3. Under The content for this source should come from, click A redirection to a URL.
> 4. In the Redirect to box, type the URL of the destination directory or Web site. For example, to redirect all requests for files
>      in the Catalog directory to the NewCatalog directory, type
>      /NewCatalog.

[IIS7: Configure the Web Server to Redirect Requests to an Exact Destination](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770409%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

> 1. Open IIS Manager and navigate to the level you want to manage. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open IIS Manager (IIS 7).
>      For information about navigating to locations in the UI based on your
>      IIS administrative role, see Navigation in IIS Manager (IIS 7).
> 2. In Features View, double-click HTTP Redirect.
> 3. On the HTTP Redirect page, under Redirect Behavior, select Redirect all requests to exact destination (instead of relative to
>      destination).
> 4. In the Actions pane, click Apply.